# Does AWS Cloudwatch combine the averages from two separate dimensions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

In the following request, I get 8 datapoints returned.

Are the 8 data points the combined averages of each day from worker-default-spot and worker-default?

The documentation does not describe what happens when two separate dimensions are passed in

```
client.get_metric_statistics(Namespace="AWS/AutoScaling", MetricName="GroupInServiceInstances",
    Dimensions=[{"Name": "AutoScalingGroupName", "Value": "worker-default-spot"},
    {"Name": "AutoScalingGroupName", "Value": "worker-default"}],
    StartTime=date_n_days_ago, EndTime=datetime.now(), Period=86400, Statistics=['Average'])
```

Comment: Those data points need some... pocket sand, sha sha!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is IMHO quite clear, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Dimension

Each combination of metrics is treated as a separate metric

Presumably you are asking for stats from 4 days ago and are getting averages for the two you are asking for over those 4 days 2x4=8

Comment: Well thats the thing, I'm asking for 8 days ago and getting 8 datapoints. The data points is simply the lower of the two dimensions data points, so it's not averaging them.